# Visual Basic break out of IF

Tags: vb.net

I have a function In Visual Basic

What i would like to be able to break out of the IF statements when an occurrence is found.

```
Private Sub GetAllPrograms2()
    ListBox4.Items.Clear()
    Dim moReturn As Management.ManagementObjectCollection
    Dim moSearch As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim mo As Management.ManagementObject
    Dim r As New Regex("(\bJava\S*|\bARR\S*|\bMicrosoft SQL Server 2\S*|\bMySQL\S*|\bPHP\S*|\bWeb C\S*|\bSmarter\S*)")
    moSearch = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Product")
    moReturn = moSearch.Get
    For Each mo In moReturn
        If r.IsMatch(mo("Name").ToString) Then
            ListBox4.Items.Add(mo("Name").ToString)
        End If
        Dim s As New Regex("(\bSQL Server 2\S*)")
        If s.IsMatch(mo("Name").ToString) Then
            If mo("Name").ToString = "Microsoft SQL Server 2012" Then
                RichTextBox1.Text += "Microsoft SQL 2012 was found" + vbCrLf
            ElseIf mo("Name").ToString = "Microsoft SQL Server 2008" Then
                RichTextBox1.Text += "Microsoft SQL 2008 was found" + vbCrLf
            ElseIf mo("Name").ToString = "Microsoft SQL Server 2005" Then
                RichTextBox1.Text += "Microsoft SQL 2005 was found" + vbCrLf
            ElseIf mo("Name").ToString = "Microsoft SQL Server 2000" Then
                RichTextBox1.Text += "Microsoft SQL 2000 was found" + vbCrLf
            End If
        End If       
    Next
End Sub
```

So what the code is doing is looking for every instance of "Microsoft SQL Server 2" it is also looking for other items but i am only concerned with "Microsoft SQL Server 2".

When it finds an occurrence of "Microsoft SQL Server 2" if will go into another IF statement and look for Microsoft SQL Server 2000, Microsoft SQL Server 2005, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Any of those it will output to a richtextbox for a report im trying to build.

The code executes fine. However when it finds more than one Program name, which sometimes with SQL there can be 10 to 20 occurrences. It outputs multiple line as many as it fines.

For instance it will find:

"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database engine shared"
"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 common files"
etc

Upon which it will output many lines of

Microsoft SQL 2012 was found
Microsoft SQL 2012 was found
etc

I would like it to just find one and move on.

I have tried using a for loop <1 however i can not for some reason get the get right.

Anyone who can help me on this would be great.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly your problem is? Do you want to escape the for-each-loop? Then you could use `Exit For` as already stated in a previous answer. You could also avoid the loop by only taking the first element of moReturn into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible - limit it in your original source (e.g. in SQL to return only one entry brute force `SELECT TOP 1` comes to mind). If that's not an option you can *exit loop* via VB.NET [Exit For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx) statement

```
IF sql found
    output some text
    Exit For
Exit
```